# Is it possible to connect to Azure Storage V2 HNS SFTP (User/Password) from Android Samsung 'MyFiles' SFTP client?

Tags: sftp, android, azure-storage

Azure Storage V2 (HNS enabled) accounts supports SFTP now and I wanted to setup a private and secure file server to migrate files between devices. I followed a Microsoft guide to set up SFTP with a 'local user' account with username and password authentication.

I then tried to connect via the Android Samsung application **My Files/Network Storage/Add Network Storage/SFTP server/**. This application doesn't support domain names, you are required to supply an IP. Azure portal does not supply this.

I tried using the connection string supplied in the Azure portal in place of the IP. This takes the form `servername.localaccount@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net`.

I tried pinging the storage account to get the IP, the IP returned was V6 unsurprisingly. The 'My Files' shows ghosted example of a V4 address. I tried using this address to connect, it did not work.

It seems that I might be trying to do something that is impossible without an application that has richer feature support.

I know that the Android Azure application supports some PowerShell CLI activities. *Perhaps* there is a built-in SFTP client that can be used to supply storage with scripts/files/whatever to support admin activities that could be used to access the account. I will look into this next.